# Store datatable in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to store DataTable in Cookies but i can't find any solution.

i have try some code but can't find any solution.

```
HttpCookie dt = new HttpCookie("dt");
```

How to add datatable in this dt.?

Comment: This first thing you need to store any object in cookies, is to *serialize* that object. Sadly, `DataTable`s are not serializable. You need to use a simpler object, such as an array or list of some simple objects.

Comment: One more point to note is that: Cookie has size limit and so may not be a good choice for storing large dataset like datatable. Apart from cache (as in your answer), you can as well use session variable.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can store values only of type String. You must convert any non-string values to strings before you can store them in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution we can not store Datatable in Cookies but we can store DataTable in Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Like answered before a cookie can store any string.

If i were you i would avoid storing it but if you really need to do so , I'd do something like this :

Assume you have the following Data-table:

Col A  Col B Col C

A      B         C

D      E         F

and so on...

I'd Store the cookie in the following way:
A,B,C;D,E,F; ... so on for as many rows that you have.

Thus you can see each row is delimited using a ';' and each column using a ','.

Later when i wish to get back the table from cookie , ill get the above string (A,B,C;D,E,F;)

I'd now have to reconstruct the table but would not need to make any DB calls.

I'd first do a String.split(";");
to get all rows of a data-table

Then for each row in Above array do a 
String.split(",") to get each value in each row .

As you can see I haven't written the entire code but seems like something any one caould do .

Also you can choose any column and row delimiter of your choice.

I'd suggest this approach only if your table isn't too large.